# Minimal prerequisite eclipse version for plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I developed a plugin using Eclipse Indigo. It depends merely on the *usual suspects* like `org.eclipse.core.runtime` etc., there is only a single unusal prerequisiste `org.eclipse.imp.runtime`.
I am quite sure that the latter should run with 3.5.

Now I have the problem telling potential users what Eclipse version they'd need at least to install it.

Will it even be installable on previous versions when developed with 3.7?

If so, how can I find out what the minimal required versions are (I hope that I do not need to edit version numbers etc. in the plugin.xml?)

If not, does this mean I have to install, say,  Eclipse 3.5 somewhere and build it there if I want to support 3.5 and higher?

Comment: Just curious...why did you choose to use imp?  My understanding is that imp is no longer being maintained and has largely been surpassed by xtext.  (Note, I am not affiliated with either project, I am really just curious for your choice.)  Thanks.

Comment: +Andrew: in fact, I looked at XText first, but it's no good when you already *have* a compiler, where at the core are some 1000 lines YACC code. I am sorry to hear that IMP should not be maintained anymore, because it is IMHO the better approach. You just don't start a new language (except maybe a very small DSL) by writing it's IDE. In addition, 1. the Xtext lexer syntax is horrible, where are the good old days of lex? where writing a lexer was just too easy. 2. lexer and parser seem not to be clearly separated 3. inferior technology - recursive descent LL(1) is really anything but appealing.

Comment: Andrew: The limitations on comment size prevented me to clarify: it's not that LL(1) is bad per se, but the front end should be able to translate the left recursive rules that are forbidden in LL(1) automatically. So, raw LL(1) at the user level is what makes writing a decent grammar a pain. Think of  `xlist = xitem | xlist ',' xitem`

Answer (score 1):

Can this help you: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Fmanifest_editor%2Fdependencies.htm

It is said, that:

> You can also specify the Minimum Version and Maximum Version of the plug-in dependency.

Comment: Alexander: This is just the problem, how do I know the minimum version of every single dependency? I know that it works on 3.7 but I suspect it could be working on 3.5. Of course, I could just say: You need 3.7, but perhaps this may needlessly distract potential users that can't give up their 3.5 for some reason.

Comment: I see....in this case the only possibility to find out the lowest version is to test:S It is probably not necessary to test each combination of plugins, but the base required plugins, like core.runtime, ui etc. ?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to install 3.5 somewhere, build, and run against it: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.php

Comment: Paul: can you just write that in an answer so I can give you your due points.